# Do we want to "set the tone" with "jenkins" questions?

Tags: discussion

Seems to me that the huge explosion of questions about `jenkins` is not really the tone for DevOps.

Answer (score 10):

I don't feel so, Jenkins is widely used as an orchestration and build tool. That sounds perfectly on topic.

The beta just opened, it sounds logical an influx on question about widely use tools come in. I feel those question are better suited here than on SO when it comes to jenkins configuration.

We should let some time to see how things evolve before frowning upon subjects.

Comment: I know this question is almost two years old at this point but I would also like to add that there is a lot more Jenkins expertise on this SE site than on others that have some topical overlap with DevOps, such as Unix & Linux, ServerFault, and SuperUser.  Unfortunately people still sometimes ask Jenkins questions on those SE sites - and sometimes Jenkins questions even get migrated to those SE sites, which is really frustrating to me, because they would receive much more attention from experts on DevOps or even StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10):

As long as the questions show good research and some level of expterise, I don't see the problem.

Though the rate at which the questions are being asked would seem to indicate that they aren't as well written as they could be.

Comment: Continuous Integration is definitely a DevOps topic, so I think questions on tooling are relevant.  I don't think we should exclude a whole topic, though I agree the quality of questions should be maintained on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 4):

As with any tool_du_jour - evaluate the question based on individual merits or lack thereof. If the question is clearly not related to Ops in some way, it doesn't belong here. If the question is about Jenkins for Jenkins sake, it doesn't belong here. If the question is about using Jenkins to automate, I'm thinking sure, why not. Especially if people are integrating orchestration pipelines.